# Limit and Taylor Series when non-differentiable

Tags: limits, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I am stuck on a problem similar to this one. 
Define $$f(\theta,y)=\frac{g(\theta y)}{\int_0^1 g(\theta x)dx}$$

with $g(0)=0$ and $\lim_{t \to 0}g'(t)=+\infty$.

I am interested in $\lim_{\theta \to 0}f(\theta,y)$. If $g'(0)$ were real, I would write:
$$g(\theta y)=\theta y g'(0)+o(\theta)$$
and
$$\int_0^1 g(\theta x)dx=\theta\int_0^1 xg'(0)dx+o(\theta)=\frac{1}{2} \theta g'(0) + o(\theta)$$

Then, for $g'(0)\ne0$, one can show that $$f(\theta,y)=\frac{2y+o(1)}{1+o(1)}$$ 
and $\lim_{\theta \to 0}f(\theta,y)=2y$.

However, I think it is wrong to write these equations when $\lim_{t \to 0}g'(t)=+\infty$. 
Can someone give me some insights on how to prove the result in this case? A result just showing that the limit is real would be enough.

Comment: Is $g$ the integral of its derivative, $$g(x) = \int_0^x g'(t)\,dt\,?$$

Comment: not necessarily, is it helpful in this case?

Comment: Maybe the change $t=\theta x$ in the integral will help?

Comment: @LaWile The functions $g(x)=x^p$, $0<p<1$ give $f(\theta,y)=(1+p)y^p$ (constant), so the limit does depend on *how* the derivative approaches $+\infty$, and to get it like $2y$ (i.e. depending only on $y$) is too optimistic hope.